# Association not recognized, undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, associations, one-to-one

I created 2 scaffolds 'mepager' and 'pimp' and linked the models like this:

```
class Mepager < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pimp
end

class Pimp < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :mepager
end
```

I added following lines to my routing:

```
resources :pimps do  
    resources :mepagers
end
```

And my mepager create action looks like this:

```
def create
    @mepager = @pimp.build_mepager(mepager_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @mepager.save
        format.html { redirect_to @mepager, notice: 'Mepager was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @mepager }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @mepager.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

And for @pimp to set

```
def setPimp
    @pimp = Pimp.find_by_id(:pimp_id)
end
```

But if I try to create a new mepager at pimps/1/mepagers/new I get an undefined method build_mepager error.

```
undefined method `build_mepager' for nil:NilClass
```

I tried the same in the rails console and it worked with just that method. So I guess somethings still missing to make it work on my web application.

Btw I m using rails 4.0.0

Regards!

Routing

> ```
> Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                 Controller#Action
> pimps GET    /pimps(.:format)                            pimps#index
> POST   /pimps(.:format)                            pimps#create
> new_pimp GET    /pimps/new(.:format)                        pimps#new
> edit_pimp GET    /pimps/:id/edit(.:format)                   pimps#edit
> pimp GET    /pimps/:id(.:format)                        pimps#show
> PATCH  /pimps/:id(.:format)                        pimps#update
> PUT    /pimps/:id(.:format)                        pimps#update
> DELETE /pimps/:id(.:format)                        pimps#destroy
> root GET    /                                           pimps#index
> pimp_mepagers GET    /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers(.:format)          mepagers#index
> POST   /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers(.:format)          mepagers#create
> new_pimp_mepager GET    /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers/new(.:format)      mepagers#new
> edit_pimp_mepager GET    /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers/:id/edit(.:format) mepagers#edit
> pimp_mepager GET    /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers/:id(.:format)      mepagers#show
> PATCH  /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers/:id(.:format)      mepagers#update
> PUT    /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers/:id(.:format)      mepagers#update
> DELETE /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers/:id(.:format)      mepagers#destroy
> GET    /pimps(.:format)                            pimps#index
> POST   /pimps(.:format)                            pimps#create
> GET    /pimps/new(.:format)                        pimps#new
> GET    /pimps/:id/edit(.:format)                   pimps#edit
> GET    /pimps/:id(.:format)                        pimps#show
> PATCH  /pimps/:id(.:format)                        pimps#update
> PUT    /pimps/:id(.:format)                        pimps#update
> DELETE /pimps/:id(.:format)                        pimps#destroy
> ```

Altered line in pimp controller

```
def create
    @pimp = Pimp.new(pimp_params)
      respond_to do |format|
      if @pimp.save
               format.html { redirect_to new_pimp_mepager_path, notice: 'Product Improvement was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @pimp }
      else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @pimp.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

mepager controller

```
class MepagersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_mepager, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def setPimp
    @pimp = Pimp.find(params[:pimp_id])
  end

  # GET /mepagers
  # GET /mepagers.json
  def index
    @mepagers = Mepager.all
  end

  # GET /mepagers/1
  # GET /mepagers/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /mepagers/new
  def new
    @mepager = Mepager.new
  end

  # GET /mepagers/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /mepagers
  # POST /mepagers.json
  def create
    raise params[:pimp_id].inspect
    @mepager = @pimp.build_mepager(mepager_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @mepager.save
        format.html { redirect_to @mepager, notice: 'Mepager was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @mepager }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @mepager.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /mepagers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /mepagers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @mepager.update(mepager_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @mepager, notice: 'Mepager was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @mepager.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /mepagers/1
  # DELETE /mepagers/1.json
  def destroy
    @mepager.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to mepagers_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_mepager
      @mepager = Mepager.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def mepager_params
      params.require(:mepager).permit(:pre, :post, :comment, :save_h, :save_c, :save_other, :save_otherv, :affect_design, :affect_stress, :affect_me, :affect_other, :affect_dno, :affect_mid, :affect_otherdoc, :owner, :pps, :reference)
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error. Is `@pimp` defined?

Comment: How are you building your form? Can you please update with your form code!

Comment: Heya, did you get it working? If so - did my answer help? If so - it's generally Good Form to "accept" the answer. you can do that by hovering your mouse over the answer... a "tick" mark appears on the left. Click that tick so it goes green and you have accepted the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, simply forgot it. Big thanks for your help! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

`@pimp = Pimp.find_by_id(:pimp_id)`

what you are doing is finding a pimp that has an id of the literal symbol `:pimp_id` (which is highly unlikely to exist)

Probably what you want is the parameter: `params[:pimp_id]`

EDIT:

and for the second part.

for the `create` action to work with a real `@pimp` (that can be found by `:pimp_id`), you *must* also do the same on the `new` action too!
Otherwise create won't work.

Can I recommend something like...

```
before_action :fetch_pimp, only: [:new, :create]


# GET /mepagers/new
def new
  @mepager = Mepager.new
end

# POST /mepagers
# POST /mepagers.json
def create
  @mepager = @pimp.build_mepager(mepager_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    # as previously...
  end
end

# ...
private
   def fetch_pimp
     @pimp = Pimp.find(params[:pimp_id])
   end
```

Comment: its `has_one :mepager` in the question

Comment: yep, I got confused because:
`resources :pimps do  
    resources :mepagers
end`

Comment: Ok, thanks for that quick answer. I changed the line to @pimp = Pimp.find(params[:pimp_id]) but its sitll no working

Comment: cool, just before that line, add this line:
`raise params[:pimp_id].inspect`
and see what you actually are getting in that parameter. Check it's what you expect for the id of a pimp

Comment: It tells me NIL so I dont really get the parameter right I guess :/ But my routing says  POST   /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers(.:format)          mepagers#create

Comment: cool... and in the action that displays this form... are you passing in a valid, saved instance of `Pimp` ?

Comment: Ok, now I see the problem but I dont know how to solve it! My application is not going to POST /pimps/:pimp_id/mepagers(.:format) mepagers#create. instead its going to  POST   /mepagers(.:format)                         mepagers#create which doenst contain the :pimp_id

Comment: Ok, 1 step foward :D I still had 'resources :mepagers' in my routes.rb! I deleted it so now the routing is working but I got some other issues because the deleted pathes are missing everywhere :/

Comment: The problem is that if you are on the `new` action, and you haven't fetched out the real `@pimp` yet... then you will have a nil `pimp_id` in the `create` form (which makes it come through as nil in the `create` action). So make sure that your `new` action is in order too.

Comment: I get your point but I manually created a pimp with the ID=1 and now i want to create a mepager that belongs to that ID and its supposed to work over the URL pimps/1/mepagers/new.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're getting at... you still need to look into the meapager#new action to make sure you are fetching the @pimp to give to the meapager#create form

Comment: Okay, I added my routing. My goal is to create a Pimp and after the creation get fowarded to the creation of a Mepager with the ID of the created Pimp. And its already working that the controller gets the ID from the URL if I type it in manually! Whats not working is the link between the two creation steps. If I created a Pimp I get fowarded to the Mepager creation but I get the error that the :pimp_id is missing. Do you know how I can take the ID of the created Pimp to the next page?

Comment: Maybe I should be clearer: I don't think the problem is with your routing... but with the code for your mepagers#new action which fetches out @pimp the first time (in the new action). Can you show us that code from your mepagers controller?

Comment: ok. So what I thought is true. you aren't setting up @pimp in the new action, and you must do that for the create action to work. Example added above.